# is there any redemption for a gentile who breaks any of the 7 Noahide laws

Tags: halacha, sin, noachide-laws

If a gentile breaks any of the 7 laws of Noah, are they doomed? Is there any way for them to redeem themselves, or is their fate sealed?

Does it depend on which laws they break and how often they break them? If so, please explain.

I understand that there may be differing opinions on this matter from various denominations. I am interested specifically in the Orthodox view.

Please let me know.

I know this is probably an uncomfortable subject but I would appreciate an honest answer

Comment: Judaism doesn't really have a concept of redemption from sin. That sounds distinctly Christian, but I'm no expert

Comment: @Double AA what about Ezekiel 18:27?

Comment: that sounds like someone who repented.

Comment: @DoubleAA Artscroll Y"K machzor under כי ביום הזה before maariv shemoneh esrei argues that repentence is a redemption and hence it's not a hefsek between geulah and tefillah.  (I don't have a good understanding of the application of semichut geulah letfillah to maariv, but that's what they say.)

Comment: Well, they can always do teshuvah (repentance). What would keep them from repenting for what they did wrong? Repentance, when done correctly, can wipe away the sin from a person.

Comment: The Book of Jonah, portrays the people of Ninveh successfully repenting.